# Is there a method to include CSS background images in print?

Tags: css, printing

Is there a method to include CSS background images in print?

If i use image replace techniques for (which is considered as a best practice) [Logo](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/lir/)  then logo doesn't come in print.

and many places in site CSS background is saving bandwidth and my time both. but client is asking to include many things in print also.

And many places where i used background images but now client need background too at some places but on some places not.

What should i do?

Can we do anything with print css?

Answer (score 2):

None of the browsers I'm aware of print backgrounds by default (to save ink/toner). I would also suggest that this is a time when using an image replacement technique is a little overkill -- for a logo the image could appear in the document (and with the relevant alternate text, still accessible)

Comment: I'm also thinking same. "Image replacement" and CSS-sprites both are overkill many time i used these to show and use my skills but faced many problematic situation in printing

Comment: The converse to that is that knowing when to use a technique (or not) is a way to show skill, too...

Comment: yes but trick i saw on well known blog and tried in projects.